# PHP regex to exactly obtain a string I want

Tags: php, regex, iframe

I have a code for embedding a link for iframe.

```
$post_contetn =  explode('htt',$content);
$content_with_link = $post_contetn[0]; 
$link = 'htt'.$post_contetn[1];
```

But the problem is that, if I write

```
http://www.espn.com  was great
```

then it links "was great" is part of the $link.

How can I change (perhaps use regex) to only include the actual url?

======

If I incorporate siam's answer, should it be

```
            $regex = '/https?:\/\/.*?(?=\s)/';
            $post_contetn = preg_match($regex, $content, $linkarray);
            $content_with_link = $post_contetn[0]; 
            $link = $linkarray[0]
            echo $content_with_link;
```

I then edited to

```
            preg_match($regex, $content, $post_contetn);
            $content_with_link = $post_contetn[0]; 
            $link = $post_contetn[0]
            echo $content_with_link;
```

But the error still occurs at echo line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following *regex* :

```
(?:https?:\/\/\S+)?\S+\.\S+\.?\S+
```

*see **[demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/WToDAO/1)***

**PHP**

```
<?php
   $content = 'http://www.espn.com  was great';
   $regex = '/(?:https?:\/\/\S+)?\S+\.\S+\.?\S+/';
   preg_match($regex, $content, $post_contetn);
   $link = $post_contetn[0];
   echo $link;
?>
```

Comment: Or `https?:\/\/\S+`

Comment: @siam Thank you! I edited my question to ask if I am correct.

Comment: @siam  I further edited my question. Error occurs at the last line "echo".  And is $link now "http://www.espn.com" ?

Comment: @user42459 you can't assign `preg_match()` to a variable. just replace `$linkarray` to `$post_contetn` and what's the format of your `$content`?

Comment: @siam  It's a string.

Comment: @siam  I further edited the question. I replaced $linkarray with $post-contetn but the error is still at echo line..

Comment: @user42459 then maybe you've something wrong with other stuff. the code works absolutely fine. see [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMUlJHOWppNDZ6WjQ)

Comment: @siam  I upvoted but there is strange thing. When the content includes only the url, it doesn't work. That is, whne "$content = 'http://www.espn.com';"  See this please : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMUlJHOWppNDZ6WjQ

Comment: @user42459 ya, that was strange. [check now](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMNldaUHdXMGM0LUU), I updated the answer.

Comment: @siam Thank you! But sorry for asking questions repeatedly... Now when there is something in front of url, it doesn't get the url correctly, e.g. ''a espn.com'    (And by the way, does php have different rule for regex? I couldn't do it with my little knowledge.)

Comment: @user42459 Its ok, you can ask question any time. anyway, I further updated the answer. now it should work fine. and NO php doesn't have different rules for *regex*.

Comment: @siam  The when the content is "asdf espn.com", the entire "asdf espn.com" is displayed. How can it be avoided and only "espn.com" is displayed?

Comment: @user42459  no, its not displaying the entire `asdf espn.com`, its only displaying `espn.com` see [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMNWlwMXBRcUQzVmM)

Comment: @siam Thank you very much!

Comment: @siam  I am sorry again but I posted a follow-up question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42686454/regex-for-filtering-out-coming-right-before-http   I really thank you for your help again.