# Regex for filtering out " coming right before http

Tags: php, regex

To make website embedding possible, the following line checks if there is `http://` or `https://`

```
        if(preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $content, $match )){
```

However, I want to filter out things like `"http://` or `"https://`  which " comes right before http.

This is because images embedding has the format

```
<img src="http://~~~.jpg">
```

and I do want to distinguish between image embedding and embeds of normal websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [*look-behind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion

```
\b(?<!")https?:\/\/[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|[^[:punct:]\s]|\/)
  ^^^^^^
```

see **[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d7Vcu8/1)**

**PHP** ( [demo](https://ideone.com/2v7rTV) )

```
$regex = '/\b(?<!")https?:\/\/[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|[^[:punct:]\s]|\/)/';
$links = 'http://www.test.com
"http://www.test.com"';
preg_match_all($regex, $links, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Thank you. But it seems your regex means "Yes if " is right before http" ? I meant "Yes if " it not right before http"   Sorry I had to be more explicit in my description.

Comment: @user42459 umm, what's your possible input strings and desired output?

Comment: Oh sorry it missed my mind. It seemed somehow work after a few attempts.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have HTML source then you want to use an HTML parser. The parser will let you distinguish tags from text, and you can then apply your transformation to the text only.

If you try as is then you also have to worry about all the ways a URL may be used in HTML. A preceding double quote will not find all of them.